# PayPal Express Checkout with display currency - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal

Just setup a multi currency web site which allows user to select **HKD**, **GB** or **USD** as display currency. However when user checkout with PayPal Express, all price change back to **USD** which is our base currency.

I Googled this problem, and I only found some solutions based on PayPal Standard.

Is it possible to checkout with PayPal Express with display currency?

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: you may extend the class that uses this  and use order currency instead of base currency.

Comment: Thanks Pratik. I am trying to rewrite Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout, start function. But up to now I can only change base_currency_code to quote_currency_code, not item price, nor amount. -_-

Comment: Your issue is related to currency or anything else?

Comment: Yes. I needed to allow user to checkout with selected currency.

Comment: then just fetch base currncy from quote and you can change it

Answer (score 1):

For accepting payment using the store currency you need to rewrite the following PayPal classes

1. Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout
2. Mage_Paypal_Model_Cart

You can see by default it's calling base currency code and base grand total, you need to change to call store currency code and grand total.

Details can be found in the below link

http://evgv.github.io/magento/paypal/currency/checkout/2016/12/15/magento-use-store-currency-to-charge-paypal-express-instead-base-currency.html